# Convert Infix expression to prefix and postfix expression with Java

Tags: java, class

I want to make an application to convert expression from infix mode to postfix and prefix mode.

For example:

infix : a+b*c

postfix: abc*+

prefix : +a*bc

I want this by two classes, a class for postfix convert and an other class for prefix convert.

In addition I have written a class for stack like this :

```
public class Stack {

int top = 0;
int stackSize = 0;
String[] stack;

public Stack(int stackSize){
    this.stackSize = stackSize;
    stack = new String[stackSize];
}

public int getTop(){
    return top;
}

public void push(String arg)throws Exception{
    if(top == stackSize){
        throw new Exception("Stack is full!");
    }
    else{
        this.stack[top++] = arg;
    }
}

public String pop()throws Exception{
    if(top == 0){
        throw new Exception("Stack is empty");
    }
    else{
        return this.stack[--top];
    }
}

public int stackCount(){
    return top++;
}
}
```

I tried this code as postfix class :

```
public class Postfix {
Stack stack = new Stack(1000);
char []operators = {'(','*','%','/','+','-',')'}; 
char[] infixExpression;
public Postfix(String infixExpression){
    this.infixExpression = infixExpression.toCharArray();
}

int priority(char operator){
    int result = 0;
    switch(operator){
    case '(':
        result = 1;
        break;
    case '*':
        result = 2;
        break;
    case '%':
        result = 3;
        break;
    case '/':
        result = 4;
        break;
    case '+':
        result = 5;
        break;
    case '-':
        result = 5;
        break;
    case ')':
        result = 7;
    }
    return result;
}

public String convertToPostfix(){
    int priority;
    String lastData;
    String exp = "";
    for(int i = 0;i<this.infixExpression.length;i++){
        priority = priority(this.infixExpression[i]);
        if(priority == 0){
            exp += this.infixExpression[i];
        }
        else if(priority == 1){
            try {
                stack.push(String.valueOf(this.infixExpression[i]));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else if(priority == 7){
            while(stack.top != 0){
                try {
                    lastData = stack.pop();
                    if(!lastData.equals("(")){
                        exp += lastData;
                    }
                    else{
                        break;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            try { 
                if(stack.top != 0){
                    while(true){
                        lastData = stack.pop();
                        stack.push(lastData);
                        if(stack.top == 0 || lastData.equals("(") || priority(lastData.toCharArray()[0]) > priority){
                            stack.push(String.valueOf(this.infixExpression[i]));
                            break;
                        }
                        exp += stack.pop();
                    }
                }else{
                    stack.push(String.valueOf(this.infixExpression[i]));
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    if(stack.top != 0){
        try {
            while(stack.top != 0){
                exp += stack.pop();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return exp;
}
}
```

but this doesn't work with Parenthesis.

Comment: I want to write two classes for postfix and prefix convert.its a mathematical project...
thanks

Comment: there is still no question. Show us what you have tried and where your problem was and we can give you help.

Comment: I have no idea to do this project
I tried to write but I had problems.
Is it necessary to write my codes here?

Comment: You should ask specific questions about problems that you have. Asking others to write the code for you is not acceptable on Stack Overflow. If you tried to write something, and encountered problems, then please ask about this and include your code.

Comment: You should search stack-overflow for other people's homework...: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[java]+infix+postfix

Answer (score -1):

All you need is:

1. Split input expression to items, split items to multipliers.
2. Add to buffer parts and delimiters in the order you need

Some bad code to do it:

```
public class Converter {

    private String infix;

    private void addMultPre(StringBuilder builder, String item) {
        String[] multipliers = item.split("[*/]");
        for (int j = 0; j < multipliers.length - 1; j++) {
            builder.append(infix.charAt(builder.length() + multipliers[j].length()));
            builder.append(multipliers[j]);
        }
        builder.append(multipliers[multipliers.length - 1]);
    }

    private void addMultPost(StringBuilder builder, String item) {
        String[] multipliers = item.split("[*/]");
        builder.append(multipliers[0]);
        for (int j = 1; j < multipliers.length; j++) {
            builder.append(multipliers[j]);
            builder.append(infix.charAt(builder.length()));
        }
    }

    public String prefix() {
        String[] items = infix.split("[+-]");
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < items.length - 1; i++) {
            builder.append(infix.charAt(builder.length() + items[i].length()));
            addMultPre(builder, items[i]);
        }
        addMultPre(builder, items[items.length - 1]);
        return builder.toString();
    }

    public String postfix() {
        String[] items = infix.split("[+-]");
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        char sign;
        addMultPost(builder, items[0]);
        for (int i = 1; i < items.length; i++) {
            sign = infix.charAt(builder.length());
            addMultPost(builder, items[i]);
            builder.append(sign);
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }

    public Converter(String infix) {
        this.infix = infix;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Converter c = new Converter("a+b*c");
        System.out.println(c.postfix());
        System.out.println(c.prefix());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
abc*+
+a*bc
```

Comment: Doesn't handle parentheses at all, and I'd be surprised if it handled operator precedence correctly.